# Kibana not showing any data from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Kibana is not showing any data, I create the index and I checked that Elasticsearch has data. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Two possible options:

1) You created kibana index-pattern, and you choose event time field options, but actually you indexed null or invalid date in this time field

2)You need to change the time range, in the time picker in the top navbar

Comment: i had to change the time range in time picker